# Mockito Deep Stubs

Tags: junit, mocking, mockito

I started using Mockito Deep Stubs recently. I have hit a roadblock while trying to deep stub a HashMap. It throws a whole lot of

```
at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethod(Class.java:2128)
    at java.util.HashMap.get(HashMap.java:556)
    at sun.reflect.Reflection.filterMethods(Reflection.java:291)
```

And following is the piece of code from where it seems to start. The

```
CloudPageBlob cloudPageBlob = Mockito.mock(CloudPageBlob.class, Mockito.RETURNS_DEEP_STUBS);
    Mockito.when(cloudPageBlob.getUri().toString()).thenReturn("id");
    Mockito.when(cloudPageBlob.getName()).thenReturn("name");
    Mockito.when(cloudPageBlob.getProperties().getLength()).thenReturn(10L);
    Mockito.when(cloudPageBlob.getMetadata().get("region")).thenReturn("region");
    Mockito.when(cloudPageBlob.getMetadata().get("performanceTierName")).thenReturn("PREMIUM");
```

*And the version of Mockito I am using is mockito-core 2.2.0*

Comment: Mockito is at version 2.8 by now. Just for to be sure; I would try latest greatest. Beyond that: read [mcve]. Try to come up with a simple example that we can run ourselves to repro the issue. Your current input is simply incomplete.

Comment: Thanks. Upgrading it to 2.8.47 solved my problem.

Comment: Why would you mock a hash map? Mocking is generally for services that are hard to unit test against. If you find yourself mocking a simple library type or pojo then there's a design fault in your software or test strategy.